# mysql select and join on multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having tables like

```
product table: product_id | code
group table:   id | fk-product_id | id_code
grade table    id | fk-product_id | id_grade
person table   id | fk-product_id | id_person
```

my sql query is:

```
"SELECT *
    FROM product 
    JOIN group  ON  group.product_id = product_id
    JOIN grade  ON  grade.product_id = product_id
    JOIN person ON person.product_id = product_id
    WHERE  product.code='".$productCode."'");
```

I get the wright result, but there is too much of rows. I thing that I'm doing overkill.

All product are for sure in the table "product" but it's not necessary that the same "id_product" is in the table "group", "grade" or "person".

In my result are a lot of rows where my result is repeted. I there any way to avoid those duplication?

Is there better way to perform my query?

Comment: Please reformat your question and provide, table structure, data sample, expected output

Comment: there's not much to reformat.

Comment: You need to provide sample data, and table structure. What you provided so far doesn't explain what doesn't work, I gave you a few example fixes, but neither solved it, so great they are incorrect. However if you want a fix you must provide the ability to see the problem and test the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your original query, you have listed the column in the group, grade and person table are 
'fk-product_id' but your query is showing as just 'product_id'.  So, I am implying your real column is just 'product_id' and the 'fk-' was just a reference that it was the foreign key to products table.

Now, that said, the equality comparison is just product_id.  Since you are not qualifying it with alias.field, it is probably grabbing everything since each record in group will always have its own product_id = its own product_id.

In addition, you mention that not all tables will have a matching product ID, so you will need LEFT-JOINs for the other tables... Adjust to something like this

```
SELECT 
      p.*,
      gp.id_code,
      gd.id_grade,
      per.id_person
   FROM 
      product p
         LEFT JOIN group gp
            ON  p.product_id = gp.product_id
         LEFT JOIN grade gd
            ON  p.product_id = gd.product_id
         LEFT JOIN person per
            ON  p.product_id = per.product_id
   WHERE
      p.code='".$productCode."'";
```

But I would head caution for sql-injection as you could get malicious values in your $productCode variable.  Make sure you have it properly cleaned and escaped.

@5er, Left-Join says for each record on the left-side (first in this case is the Product Table), I want all records... and oh... by the way... I have the other tables (group, grade and persons).  They MAY have a record too that has the same Product_ID value as the product table.  If so, grab those pieces too, but don't exclude the original product record.

Now, why your query was failing, and I thought I described it well, but apparently not.  You were getting a Cartesian result which means for every one record in the left-table (product), you were getting EVERY record in the RIGHT-side table... So, for a single product, and if you had 20 group, 10 grades and 100 people, you were basically getting 20,000 records.

So your JOIN

```
JOIN group  ON  group.product_id = product_id
```

WOULD have worked, but had less records IF you qualified with the PRODUCT reference

```
JOIN group  ON  group.product_id = PRODUCT.product_id
```

Otherwise, it was just comparing its own product_ID to itself and saying... Yup, these to product IDs match (even though it was the same record), it returned it.  The engine can't guess for you which table you meant for the second part of the join, especially when there were a total of 4 tables referenced in the query, and EACH had a "Product_ID" column.  So, I strongly suggest that for ALL your queries, qualify ALL fields as alias.field, including those of the select field list.  Then, anyone else trying to help you in the future, or even take over where you left-off know where the fields are.  Prevent ambiguity in your queries.

Comment: He complains of duplicates, I don't think its because of ``JOIN`` vs ``LEFT JOIN``, thought I am no longer sure as he hasn't provided enough information

Comment: @nrathaus, yes, duplicates.  His query had nothing qualifying TableA.Field to JoinTableB.Field.  Since each of the Join tables have the column "Product_ID", then it was basically qualifying the Group.Product_ID = its own Group.Product_ID thus ALWAYS true and creating a Cartesian result.

Comment: Finding an answer here is hopeless, as the question and potential solution cannot be found as there is insufficient information on what is lacking @DRapp

Comment: Thank you. It seems that this is working. I was previously form my statemant with INNER JOIN , when I should use LEFT JOIN. Can you explain me, what is big difference here against JOIN. I mean does, it working faster?

Comment: @5er, see revised answer for clarification to join / performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your results are repeating because the `JOIN` is joining tables, but you are not filtering those cases where one `JOIN` matches, while the other isn't.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM product 
JOIN group  ON  group.product_id = product.id
JOIN grade  ON  grade.product_id = product.id
JOIN person ON person.product_id = product.id
WHERE  product.code='".$productCode."'
GROUP BY product.id
```

Comment: This will work only if you are expecting to have all three tables to exist per product_id, is this the case? if not please fix the above question to explain

Comment: That is not what I asked, I asked, do you expect all 4 tables to have the same id for the product? i.e. if table ``product`` has product ``id`` 5, does ``group``, ``grade``, and ``person`` also have this product id 5?

Comment: What kind of duplicates are you seeing? are you seeing them when more than two table have results?

Comment: Try the GROUP BY I added

Comment: well, every row is unique. but duplicated are things like id_grade. all rows have the same id_grade, and also other stuff.

Comment: Did GROUP BY help you?

Comment: What information are you losing? it would be great if you could be more informative, if you aren't no one can help you. I cannot continue this guess work or investigative work, you need to reformat your question and provide, table structure, data sample, expected output

Answer (score 0):

Your select does not match the table/column names above it. For example in table product you say you have column id_product, but in select you use product.id instead of product.id_product. That might be totally different column.

Comment: he writes, fk-id_product he means ``foreign key``, so the columns match

Comment: After the question update now it is better, but still the names do not match (id_product vs. product_id).

Comment: that is true. there are some semantic mistakes, but this is example. my problem is similar, but a little bigger statement, and would be hard for people to read it. I will fix it.

Comment: Now I'm not sure this would help, but try using table_name.column_name notation on every join - for example for the first join, it should be `JOIN group  ON  group.product_id = product.product_id`